# Telnet command to configure an extern server

Tags: telnet

I need to telnet a remote server on a different network

When i am at the network I can use the command "telnet 192.168.0.1 25" in commandprompt.
Is it possible to do the same at an extern network?
The WAN IP of that server is 81.82.X.X:3389 but because I need a port to get the correct server I can't fill in the port 25 anymore...

PS: Yes I know telnet is an old protocol but I still need to use it

Comment: You realize that "3389" is not part of the IP address, right?

Comment: Yes but I need that port to get the specific server 192.168.0.1